# What is the practical different between the usage of JSON and YAML in Swagger?

Tags: json, yaml, swagger

It appears that JSON includes the path information and http request verb, whereas YAML seems to just definition a tree structure alone.

What is the difference between them?  Or am I mixing up different concepts/hierarchies here?  newbie to swagger, just started learning.

If YAML is a superset of JSON what specifically is the superset adding here - is it URL paths and HTTP verbs ?  Is adding an `example` also something that YAML adds to JSON for Swagger ?

Answer (score 30):

According to the [OpenAPI Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md),

> An OpenAPI document that conforms to the OpenAPI Specification is itself a JSON object, which may be represented either in JSON or YAML format.

So feature-wise, there is no difference between using JSON or YAML. What YAML as a superset of JSON adds here is merely a different syntax. Using an example from the specification, these two documents are identical:

```
{
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://development.gigantic-server.com/v1",
      "description": "Development server"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://staging.gigantic-server.com/v1",
      "description": "Staging server"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.gigantic-server.com/v1",
      "description": "Production server"
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
servers:
- url: https://development.gigantic-server.com/v1
  description: Development server
- url: https://staging.gigantic-server.com/v1
  description: Staging server
- url: https://api.gigantic-server.com/v1
  description: Production server
```

The first document is valid JSON and valid YAML (since YAML is a superset of JSON). The second document is valid YAML and structurally identical to the first document.

So to answer the question about what the YAML superset adds here: It adds different syntax for specifying the same structures. Nothing more.

<sub><sup>YAML does include some features that are not mappable to JSON, but they are irrelevant here because Swagger/OpenAPI doesn't use them.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 30):

JSON does not support comments, while YAML does!

Comment: I was thinking why I should use one over the other, until I read this point. Comments could be very useful in development (i.e: I can add to-do items!). I guess it could be viewed as the difference between a document (yaml) vs data (json)

Comment: Though, imo, any comments should be baked into the document itself, not on the YAML spec level.

Answer (score 0):

YAML is neater, easier to read and write than JSON if you look at it from another angle.